# How do I sanitise a user-provided URL before a GET request?

Tags: python, security, request

I am writing a Telegram bot that notifies me when a web page changes. I provide a URL, which is periodically fetched via `requests.get` and hashed. If the hash is different from the previous one, I'm notified.

I am willing to open it to the rest of the community, but then I need to guard against malicious usage and abuse. So far I guarded against users providing links to gigantic files but, given my minimal knowledge of the subject, I suspect there is more to it than that.
My questions are then:

1. What kinds of attacks am I exposing myself to?
2. How do I defend?

Comment: With user input URL parameter, you are also exposing your internal network. Just for example, if your database is running on port 5000 and the attacker then inputs the URL as http://localhost:5000. Similarly if you were on a cloud network EC2 instance, then depending upon the output of the app, I could try  `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/` to exfiltrate credentials depending on app's output to the URL  or try 192.168.0.0/16 to scan your internal network. This is just the one kind of attack scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the examples. The user never gets any output, the code just fetches and hashes, and that's about it. Ways to limit those cases might include running the bot as a different user with limited rights, or having a blacklist to check the requested URL against. How does it sound?

Comment: yes make sure to allow only http and https protocol and nothing like ftp,ssh etc etc
You could reference this document, which matches your scenario
https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Server_Side_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html

I'm bit skeptical on the direct usage of requests.get

Comment: I have no obligation to directly use `requests.get`. If you know a better method, I'm all ears.

Comment: sockets maybe, not sure though..